# ubuntu 15.10 mouse & touchpad missing settings in settings

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 15.10

my 15.10 image installs fine but has no 2 finger scrolling settings. 14 lts had two folder in that panel, but this one lost all the cool stuff. is there a fix?

regards bjorn o.